# More Effecient Way to Format Dates for in Python for MySQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, date-format, mysql-connector-python

Say I have a list of dates that are formatted in one of the five ways below:

```
Date_Type_1 = 2001 Apr 15
Date_Type_2 = 2001 Apr
Date_Type_3 = 2000 Spring
Date_Type_4 = 2000 Nov-Dec
Date_Type_5 = 2001
```

So that my date list will look like this.

```
Date_list = ["2001 Apr 15", "2004 May 15", "2011 Jan", "2011 Fall", "2000 Nov-Dec", "2012", "2000 Spring" ]
```

I now want to try and format these dates so they can be passed to a MySQL database.  The only way I know how is to use a lot of condition flow.  Here is an example of how I would do this.  I will not include ALL conditions as it would take up too much space.

```
for i in Date_list:
  year = i[:4]
  #This will be my conditional logic to define a month.
  #This is only an example.  Will not include all 12 months, 4 seasons, and various bi-months
  if "Apr" in i and "Mar-Apr" not in i:
     month = 4
  if "Mar-Apr" in i:
     month = 3
  if "May" in i and "May-Jun" not in i:
     month = 5
  if "Apr-May" in i:
     month = 4
  if "Spring" in i:
     month = 3
  #This will be conditional logic to define the day.
  #I would do this for each of the 31 days of the month.
  if "15" in i and "2015" not in i:
     day = 15

 date_return = datetime.datetime(year,month,day)
 date_format = date_return.date().isoformat
```

The issue with this is that I am making a number of assumptions.  I am okay with defining seasons "Spring/Summer.." and the bi-monthly (e.g. Mar/Apr) returns as specific months.  The issue, at least with defining days is it will not catch days if:

```
test_list = [2011 May, 2015 Apr 15]
for i in test_list:
  if "15" in i and "2015" not in i:
    day = 15
```

This will not catch the day.  I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?  This current method would require 50+ conditional statements to define the day/months.

Comment: I dont think your code is slow, but looks like your efficient mean shorter version.

Comment: Both of these are great answers and very elegant.  Thank you, I wish I could pick both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Python regular expression module `re`. It's a lot better for this than trying to mess with slices and `in`.

```
import re

MONTHS = [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 
    'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
SEASONS = { 'Spring': 'Mar', 'Summer': 'Jun', 'Fall': 'Sep', 
    'Autumn': 'Sep', 'Winter': 'Dec' }

_MONTHS_RE = '|'.join(MONTHS)
_SEASONS_RE = '|'.join(SEASONS)
DATE_RE = re.compile(r"""(?ax) # ASCII-only verbose mode
    (?P<year>20[0-9]{2}) # Year
    ( # followed by either...
        (?P<month>""" + _MONTHS_RE + r""") # a month name then...
        (   -(?P<endmonth>""" + _MONTHS_RE + r""") # a month range
        |   (?P<day>[1-9][0-9]?) # a day number
        )? # range and day are optional 
    |   (?P<season>""" + '|'.join(SEASONS) + r""") # or a season.
    )""")

def parse_date(datestr):
    m = DATE_RE.match(datestr)
    if m is None:
        return # Didn't match
    md = m.groupdict()
    year = int(md["year"])
    if "season" in md:
        month = SEASONS[md["season"]]
    else:
        month = md["month"]
        if "endmonth" in md:
            # handle month range here.
        day = int(md.get("month", 1))
    return year, month, day
    # Month is returned as a string; to get a number, use:
    return year, MONTHS.index(month) + 1, day
```

Note that this doesn't ensure that the date exists; it will accept `"2099 Jun 50"` or many other bad dates. But I'll leave filtering that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dates = ["2001 Apr 15", "2004 May 15", "2011 Jan", "2011 Fall", "2000 Nov-Dec", "2012", "2000 Spring" ]
>>>
>>> def convert(date_str):
...     tokens = date_str.split(' ')
...     if len(tokens) == 1:
...         date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y')
...     elif len(tokens) == 3:
...         date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y %b %d')
...     elif len(tokens) == 2 and '-' in tokens[1]:
...         date_str = date_str.split('-')[0]
...         date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y %b')
...     else:
...         seasons = {
...             'spring': 'Mar',
...             'fall': 'Sep',
...         }
...         if tokens[1].lower() in seasons.keys():
...             date_str = '{} {}'.format(tokens[0], seasons[tokens[1].lower()])
...         date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y %b')
...     return date_time.date().isoformat()
...
>>>
>>> for date_str in dates:
...     print '{} === {}'.format(date_str, convert(date_str))
...
2001 Apr 15 === 2001-04-15
2004 May 15 === 2004-05-15
2011 Jan === 2011-01-01
2011 Fall === 2011-09-01
2000 Nov-Dec === 2000-11-01
2012 === 2012-01-01
2000 Spring === 2000-03-01
```